# Pacemaker Virtual IP suddenly Failed

Tags: cluster, sles, pacemaker, sap

I am new in cluster.

We are running SAP Application in HA Cluster (have 2 nodes in cluster) using pacemaker. Node1 if it runs as a master always restart for a few times. After we check pacemaker logs, we found resource IP float (Virtual IP) failed in node1. May I know What is the rootcause for this problem and how to mitigate this issue ??.

Comment: The logs should have more clues hinting to the root cause. The `crm_mon` output should show the failures with a timestamp. Check the logs around that time.

Comment: I already check the logs, but the clue from the logs only this : ```2022-04-29T20:43:18.863881+07:00 erpswdeapapp1 pacemaker-execd[3016]:  notice: rsc_ip_float_monitor_10000[9741] error output [ /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/IPaddr2: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable ]```. Why resource temporarily unavailable ??, do you have any experience about this ??.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configurated 'migration-threshold' like as: [https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/deprecated/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-failure-migration.html#:~:text=Pacemaker%20allows%20you%20to%20set,no%20threshold%20defined%20by%20default](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/deprecated/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-failure-migration.html#:%7E:text=Pacemaker%20allows%20you%20to%20set,no%20threshold%20defined%20by%20default).